# Error when saving file using .ExportAsFixedFormat

Tags: vba, excel

I have run a macro which generates a sheet that I want to save as a PDF.  When I run the method below, I get the error telling me my document was not saved (`Run=time error '-2147024773 (8007007b)': Document not saved`.

I beleive it may be the filename that I am trying to give it...but unsure.  Happy to provide any further information.

All variables are publicly declared

```
Public Sub toPDF()

    PDFName = "Pinger Report_" & Format(Now, "dd/mm/yyyy hh:mm:ss")
    sumPDFSheet.Cells(5, 4).Value = Format(Now, "dd/mm/yyyy hh:mm:ss")

    finalPDFName = PDFPath & PDFName

    'create borders around failed devices range on pdfsheet
        With sumPDFSheet.Range(sumPDFSheet.Cells(24, 3), sumPDFSheet.Cells(k - 1, 5)).Borders
    .LineStyle = xlContinuous
    End With

    'creates heading rows for each page in the pdf and centers correctly
    sumPDFSheet.PageSetup.PrintTitleRows = sumPDFSheet.Rows(1).Address
    sumPDFSheet.PageSetup.CenterVertically = False
    sumPDFSheet.PageSetup.CenterHorizontally = True

    'method call to format columns
    allColumns

    'save as pdf to correct folder with correct name
    With sumPDFSheet
        .ExportAsFixedFormat Type:=xlTypePDF, Filename:=finalPDFName, openafterpublish:=False 'ERRRORRRRRRRRRERRRR
    End With

End Sub
```

Comment: what's the value in the variable "finalPDFName" ? Is the the file extension correct ?

Comment: Thanks for pointing out. You were correct on file extension.

Answer (score 2):

Answer: Correct File extension to be provided.

Comment: Sorry to necro - could you explain further how you fixed this? Where did you add the correct file extension?